# motion tracking javascript = html5/canvas game input/control

Tags: javascript, html, input, detection, motion

motion tracking with camera with javascript???? = input for game. is there a framework or something that might have this?

other words...besides, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, xbox/ps3/usb joystick input i am wanting to further dig into camera motion detection, as a form of input / control for the game. and if i need to take into account certain extra variables, or extra button pressings (onmousedown) or key presses (onkeydown) or joystick button pressed (ongamepad) or i guess i should say motion pressing (????) = (onmotiontrack) ????

i did come across

[Camera object detection in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294258/camera-object-detection-in-javascript)

http://phys.org/news197792915.html

http://www.scriptcam.com/docs.cfm

but unsure if there is a specific standard (framework) or gestures or like for fingers / hands / eyes / eyelids / head movement. that is out there?

i do not want to see the video, i just want the "input" or rather "motion tracking" other words...

```
X finger moves left = move mouse left
Y finger lifts up = double click of amouse
Z finger lowers down = click
Z finger lowers down and moves right = drag
A finger lifts up and moves left = second mouse pointer or rotation of character
```

is there any spacial info X,Y,Z  i need to take into account, or is the motion tracking doing, only returns "keydown, or keyup",  vs a joystick angalog sticks X,Y axis and how much on each axis.

Answer (score 3):

There are some frameworks:

- [videotracker.js](http://lusob.github.io/videotracker.js/)
- [headtrackr](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/)